# Удаление данных из бд

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужно сделать удаление из бд через dataGrid. Делаю удаление через стандартную панельку которая идёт вместе с dataGrid, только добавил кнопку для обновления данных в бд. Но почему-то удаление работает только если запускать exe файл. К тому же если запустить снова проект, то строка, которую я удалил возвращается. Не могу понять почему так.

```
   this.призначенняTableAdapter.Update(this.apteka1DataSet.Призначення);
```

Код кнопки.

Comment: Покажите код, пожалуйста.

Comment: Так, я понял в чем проблема. У меня 2 бд:одна в папке с проектом, вторая в папке с exe файлом.Если запускать через exe, то в бд, которая в папке с exe, меняется. Если запустить проект, то проект работает с бд, которая в папке с проектом. В итоге открывая проект у меня строки из одной бд перекрывают другую. Если удалить одну из них, то не будет запускаться либо проект, либо exe.

Comment: Хорошо, что все решилось. Вспомнил что, один преподаватель в ВУЗе ввел такую практику: носил с собой на пары мягкую игрушку. Если у тебя вопрос, то он дает игрушку и надо сначала спросить у неё (причем без шуток, нормально спросить, как у человека). Если проблема не решилась - уже вопрос к преподавателю.

Comment: Да как бы не решилось. Я не понимаю что делать. 2 бд это не дело, а удалить их нельзя.

Comment: Всё можно, только у вас действительно не должно быть 2 БД. Почему так происходит - нужно понять, а для начала - нужно больше информации, какие БД, как вы их подключаете, какие пути для подключения/обращения используются.

Comment: Проверьте строку подключения к СУБД. Если есть путь - путь к базе должен быть абсолютным. Если путь относительный, то для debug и release версии они пути могут быть разные.

Comment: Подключал в Visual Studio через Data source. Бд Access, изначально кидал бд в папку с проектом и туда же указывал путь, позже бд скопировалась в папку debug.

Comment: В свойствах той БД, что в проекте, смотрите пункт `Copy to Output Directory` - очевидно, там стоит `Copy Always`. Поставьте `Do not copy` - тогда БД не будет копироваться в папку с exe-файлом. Естественно, путь к БД нужно подправить. Или поставьте `Copy if newer` - тогда БД будет копироваться только в том случае, если вы в ней что-то изменили (схему).

Comment: В самом проекте этот пункт ?